# What is the history of the cursive p?

Tags: british-english, writing-style, writing, contemporary-english, handwriting

A friend of mine (relevant detail, he grew up and learned cursive in India) recently remarked to me that he missed the way that cursive "p"s used to be written. An example of this can be seen in the following image:

[image: Image of example word "propagator", the stem of the lower case p extends well above the "loop" of the p.]

I'm used to a p which doesn't have such a high rise on the left stem of the p. Another example of the p that I am used to is below.

[image: IMage of example lowercase cursive alphabet]

Is anyone aware of the origin (time or location) of this style of p? Though my friend is from India, the example comes from the lectures of the Professor Dr. Richard Feynman, so it must have been taught in the United States as well.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I can't see how it's [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on a site about *English language and usage*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about EL&U, and it likely isn't even about English.

Comment: Do what you must, but in doing so, please explain to me how a question about the physical representation of a language is not about the language. I realize this isn't the sort of question that is typically asked on this site, but of the stack exchange sites, this is the best fit for this question. Here's an example of another question, similarly concerned with the representation of individual letters, that was not closed as being off-topic: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/386383/318156

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer ...

See the explanation of the [Palmer method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmer_Method).  It has the high stroke on the 'p'.

In around 1958, We were supposedly taught the "Palmer method" of writing ... but it did not have the high stroke on the 'p'.  And the capital 'F' was much more difficult.  (The other letters on that page look like what we learned.) So it was I guess some modification of that method.